# How can I reach a variable loaded in another callback function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to load a neural network object file with a pushbutton and use it in other pushbutton's callback function.

I am not using GUIDE, I am creating the GUI programmatically. Here is my code:

```
function ASR()

figure('Name','Automatic Isolated Speech Rcognition System',.......
   'Menubar','none',........
   'Color',[1 1 1]);

Rcrd_and_Recog =uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',....
                           'Units','normalized',....
                           'Position',[0.75 0.75 0.20 0.05],....
                           'String','START',....
                           'Callback',@Record_Recog);

LD_net = uicontrol('Style','pushbutton',....
                            'Units','normalized',....
                            'Position',[0.75 0.65 0.20 0.05],....
                            'String','LOAD THE NET',....
                            'Callback',@load_net);

function load_net(varargin)
    [file path]=uigetfile('*.mat','Select the M-file');
    if ~isequal(file, 0)
        L=load(fullfile(path,file));
        Net=fieldnames(L);
        net=Net{1};
        handles.net=net;
    end

 function Record_Recog(varargin)
     fs=16000;
     y=wavrecord(1*fs,fs,1,'double');

     if length(y)<1157
         result=sim(net0,cat(1,y,zeros(1157-length(y),1)))
     else
         result=sim(net0,y)
     end
 end
```

I loaded the `net` variable but I cannot reach it from `Rcrd_and_Recog`. How can I reach it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where net0 is declared. 
You should use global variables if you want to share them between different functions

Comment: PLZ ; someone help me i am stuck here for 2 days.

Comment: Hello world can u just more describe the process u mentioned; or specifically tell me where i have to edit in my code.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If it's still relevant I see you want to load the variable and save it somewhere and then use it in some other place. One option is what you seemed to try to do is save it to some other object but then you need a label or a text box but not just handles.net=net; or you could declare it as global variable by writing at the begining of the function load_net the words "global net" this will mean you can now use this variable in other functions. Then in the function "Record_Recog" you write "global net" and then use it and not the net0 which is not used anywhere else.